Zipstream file cant be open
I am trying to create zip file using php package zip stream but it seems like its not creating proper zip, after download i cant be able to open it on mac and windows too, when i checked with online tool it say empty zip. could some body help me in this regard. attached code snippet
$zip = new \ZipStream\ZipStream(
                    outputName: 'test.zip',
                    // defaultEnableZeroHeader: true,
                    sendHttpHeaders: true,
                    contentType: 'application/x-zip',
                    
                );

                $zip->addFile(
                    fileName: 'hello.txt',
                    data: 'This is the contents of hello.txt',
                    compressionMethod : CompressionMethod::DEFLATE,
                    
                    // deflateLevel: 9
                );



                return $zip->finish();

i tried with multiple php packages but getting same result with all of them

Try opening the file in a text-based editor such as notepad on Windows. A zip file is a binary file so you shouldn’t see much if any text. If you see any text such as HTML or error messages, something else is leaking into the HTTP stream along with the file.
